# Can't remove a space below div element

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am creating a chat like application. And there is a space below timestamp and I can't remove it.

```css
.message {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.message-avatar {
    float: left;
    margin 5 px 14px 0 0;
}

  .message-from {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 8px;
  }

  .message-timestamp {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .message-body {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 0 0 8px;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
```

```html
<div class="message">
    <v-img class="message-avatar" src="..."></v-img>
    <small class="message-from">User</small>
    <div class="message-timestamp"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="message-body"></div>
</div>
```

How can I remove it? It appears only below `message-timestamp` and I don't set any margin and padding below the element.

## Update

I found out a thing. The space after `timestamp` might be whitespaces. At least on console it is displayed as whitespaces. I can remove this manually on console so I tried to just remove the whitespaces but I can't do it programmatically.

Comment: Missing css attribute in class message-avatar

Comment: @user8063037 Ah sorry it's just my mistake when posting this. I updated

Comment: why there is a empty div?

Comment: @AashifAhamed The message body (inline-block) will be right to timestamp if I remove this. Sorry if it's a weird way I am not good at css.

Comment: remove the empty div after **message-timestamp**

Comment: @PRADIPGORULE No even if I remove this `message-body` will be right to `message-timestamp` and there is still a space below `message-timestamp`.

Comment: Can you upload a screen shot of the actual bug. that might be helpful

Comment: dont remove the **message-body** remove `<div></div>` which is in between the **message-timestamp** and **message-body**  classs

Comment: @PRADIPGORULE I mean if I remove the empty div `message-body` cannot be placed below `message-timestamp`. It will be right to `message-timestamp`.

Comment: you are using [`white-space: pre-wrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space). so, it preserves the white space in your markup.  [Checkout the result](https://codepen.io/krish4u/pen/yLyXmxV) without `pre-wrap`

Comment: just remove the empty div and add css to **.message-body**  `  display: block;` not a `  display: inline-block;`

Comment: @PRADIPGORULE `padding` between `message-avatar` and `message-body` doesn't work if I do it.

Comment: will you please show me the output of your html screen

Comment: @Krish Ah that is the cause of this problem.. I removed it and set it on `message-body` instead of `message` and it is solved.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ooto : u r welcome

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what look you're trying to accomplish but it seems like you have some competing styles. If you get rid of the pre-wrap and the inline-block displays your blank space disappears.

See this scratchpad as an example:
http://scratchpad.io/stormy-toys-7510

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues like this in the past, and I usually try to manipulate it with some CSS Flex.

```css
.message {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.message-avatar {
    float: left;
    margin 5 px 14px 0 0;
}

.message-fix {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

  .message-from {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 8px;
  }

  .message-timestamp {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .message-body {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 0 0 8px;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
```

```html
<div class="message">
    <v-img class="message-avatar" src="..."></v-img>
    <div class="space-fix">
        <small class="message-from">User</small>
        <div class="message-timestamp"></div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="message-body"></div>
</div>
```

Also, try using JavaScript to trim the value of the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`white-space: pre-wrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) So, it preserves the **white space** in your HTML markup. Remove the `white-space` property and check. Replicated your HTML mockup without [`white-space: pre-wrap`](https://codepen.io/krish4u/pen/yLyXmxV).

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

**CSS**:

```
.message-timestamp::after {
    display: none;
}
```